# How to DRY up 2 controllers/models/views that are basically the exact same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, dry

An `Order` has_many `AItems` and `BItems`. As you can tell, the items are basically identical but with an important business reason for categorizing them separately. Wondering what's the best strategy to DRY this up. I realize this is a little opinionated... but hoping to get some clear points of view and arguments.

**View code**

Currently I'm using a partial. Like this:

```
class AItemsController
  def new
  end
end

class BItemsController
  def new
  end
end

# view files layout
> views
  > AItems
    > new.html.erb
  > BItems
    > new.html.erb

# routing
get '/AItems/new'
get '/BItems/new'

# code for /views/AItems/new.html.erb
<%= render "layouts/items_new", object: "AItems" %>

# code for /views/BItems/new.html.erb
<%= render "layouts/items_new", object: "BItems" %>
```

I'm wondering if it'd be easier to get rid of the partial entirely and just do parameters like this:

```
class AItemsController
  def new
  end
end

class BItemsController
  def new
  end
end

# view files layout
> views
  > Items
    > new.html.erb

# routing
get '/items/new/:type'

# code for /views/Items/new.html.erb
# code from partial evaluating the param[:type] instead of a passed object
```

**Controller code**

Currently everything is duplicated... (I haven't made any attempt at DRYing yet) as in it looks like this (very illustrative, the point is to just show that short of the naming conventions literally everything is basically the same):

```
class AItemsController
  def new
    @items = AItems.joins(:order).where("orders.status_id IS NULL")
  end

  def do_something
    a_items_params.each do |item_params|
      key_var = item_params[:some_attribute]
      ...
    end
  end
end

class BItemsController
  def new
    @items = BItems.joins(:order).where("orders.status_id IS NULL")
  end

  def do_something
    b_items_params.each do |item_params|
      key_var = item_params[:some_attribute]
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't DRYed this yet because I'm a little conflicted as to how. Examples below are illustrative, forgive if the code isn't exact, but hopefully you get the gist.

**Solution A:** In one way, I could keep the action definitions in each controller, and then have the code within the action pull from a shared concern:

```
class AItemsController
  include SharedCode

  def new
    shared_new
  end

  def do_something
    shared_do_something
  end
end
```

**Solution B:** abstract away the action definitions to the shared concern:

```
class AItemsController
  included SharedAction

  shared_action("AItems")
end
```

**Solution C:** route everything to a singular controller and again use params to differentiate (passed from view)

```
class ItemsController
  def new
    item_type = params[:item_type]
  end

  def do_something
    item_type = params[:item_type]
  end
end
```

**Model code**

This one is a little more cut and dry, and I don't need a ton of feedback here, I will just used shared concerns for key methods/ callback.

---

Obviously the answer for one will affect the other. For example if everything routes through a single controller, then I'll have a single view with parameters rather than a partial approach. But because the controller has multiple DRYing options, there's still room for debate.

If you've read this far, I will happily take angry comments about how this question is too loosely defined in exchange for at least some thoughts on what you would do. What's more understandable for you if you were taking over my code?

I am trying to learn and the best way to do that is to solicit multiple points of view and pros and cons to weigh out.

Comment: You could use inheritance probably, but why not use one item table and just have a tag for A items and B items?

Comment: I agree with the above (single table inheritance). But there is another option: Subclass the ItemsController. eg use Solution C but then have `AItemsController < ItemsController` with eg a private method that defines the item-class to use

Comment: MageeWorld it's purely a business reason that they're kept separate, not a code reason. It makes our accounting much faster/easier. TarynEast I like that idea, good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **InheritedResources Gem**: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

> Inherited Resources speeds up development by making your controllers
>   inherit all restful actions so you just have to focus on what is
>   important. It makes your controllers more powerful and cleaner at the
>   same time.

Or the **Responders Gem**, a replacement to Inherited Resources: https://github.com/plataformatec/responders

> A set of responders modules to dry up your Rails 4.2+ app.